# test "pthread_create" function behaviour

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am new in multi-threaded programming and I have a question about "pthread_create" behaviour
this is the code :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NTHREADS      10
#define ARRAYSIZE   1000000
#define ITERATIONS   ARRAYSIZE / NTHREADS

double  sum=0.0, a[ARRAYSIZE];
pthread_mutex_t sum_mutex;


void *do_work(void *tid) 
{
  int i, k=0,start, *mytid, end;
  double mysum=0.0;

  mytid = (int *) tid;
  start = (*mytid * ITERATIONS);
  end = start + ITERATIONS;
  printf ("Thread %d doing iterations %d to %d\n",*mytid,start,end-1);  
  for (i=start; i < end ; i++) {
    a[i] = i * 1.0;
    mysum = mysum + a[i];
    }

  sum = sum + mysum;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, start, tids[NTHREADS];
  pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
    tids[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL/*&attr*/, do_work, (void *) &tids[i]);
   }

  /* Wait for all threads to complete then print global sum */ 
/*
  for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }*/
  printf ("Done. Sum= %e \n", sum);

  sum=0.0;
  for (i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++){ 
  a[i] = i*1.0;
  sum = sum + a[i]; }
  printf("Check Sum= %e\n",sum);

}
```

the result of execution is :

```
Thread 1 doing iterations 100000 to 199999
Done. Sum= 0.000000e+00 
Thread 0 doing iterations 0 to 99999
Thread 2 doing iterations 200000 to 299999
Thread 3 doing iterations 300000 to 399999
Thread 8 doing iterations 800000 to 899999
Thread 4 doing iterations 400000 to 499999
Thread 5 doing iterations 500000 to 599999
Thread 9 doing iterations 900000 to 999999
Thread 7 doing iterations 700000 to 799999
Thread 6 doing iterations 600000 to 699999
Check Sum= 8.299952e+11
```

all thread are created and the execution is not sequential (remove pthread_join), but the function do_work is executed in order and depend on thread. it means iterations 0 to 99999 are done by thread 0 and iterations 100000 to 199999 are done by thread 1 etc ...

the question is here why for example iterations 0 to 99999 is not done by thread 2 ?

Comment: You don't use the mutex you have defined. You should use the mutex to access global variables. Also, you pass the `&tids[i]` which has been assigned `i`. YOur `start` and `end` are based on this input. Hence, the output

Comment: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because iteration range is calculated based on thread number from 0 to N in the following line:

```
start = (*mytid * ITERATIONS);
```

And you create and pass that number in a loop as such:

```
for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
    tids[i] = i;
    ...
```

In other words, 2 + N will never be 0 to perform iteration over 0 to 99999 when N is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused as to what threads are.
Think about each thread as its own program.  If you run 10 programs at the same time, they will be running "simultaneously", i.e. instructions of these 10 programs will be interleaved, but within each program all instructions are executed in the deterministic order.
Same thing with threads.  You define which numbers each thread will iterate over by passing the thread id argument when creating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the address of `tids[i]`<sup>th</sup> variable to thread `i` and printing based on it. In this case `N`<sup>th</sup> thread will always print from `N000000` till `N999999` without any change in all the trial runs.

```
mytid = (int *) tid;
start = (*mytid * ITERATIONS);
end = start + ITERATIONS;
```

For thread 2, it would behave as,

```
mytid = (int *) tid;                    // *mytid = 2
start = ( 2 * ITERATIONS);              // 2000000
end = ( 2 * ITERATIONS) + ITERATIONS;   // 2999999
```

Thus printing `2000000` to `2999999`. So you can't expect `thread 2` to print `0 to 99999`.

---

It is not wise to use global variables like `sum`, which are shared between threads, without any kind of locking mechanisms. They would bring unexpected results. Use of `pthread_mutex`  here would solve this problem.